# VBA type mismatch error when deleting pictures

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to delete all pictures in a range.
I found the below code online but its throwing a type mismatch error on row:

```
For Each pic In ws.Pictures
```

Any input or alternative code is much appreciated.

```
Sub clearPics()
Dim s As String
Dim pic As Picture
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("sort")
Set rng = ws.Range("c:c")

For Each pic In ws.Pictures
    With pic
        s = .TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & .BottomRightCell.Address
    End With
    If Not Intersect(rng, ws.Range(s)) Is Nothing Then
        pic.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks,
jj

Comment: I always struggle with this kind of code, but does changing it to `Dim pic as Shape` fix it?

Comment: The Microsoft worksheet.pictures documentation shows it being object. I would change it to Dim pic as Object. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.pictures(v=vs.120).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: @Jeeped, I was hoping that the `In ws.Pictures` part would deal with that, but totally untested so I don't know.

Comment: @PKatona changing to Object worked. But it is also deleting radio buttons, drop downs and checkboxes on the sheet. How do you delete only pictures?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090578/ms-access-determine-object-type

Answer (score 0):

You have declare pic as Picture.
Rename `Dim pic` to something else like `Dim pic1` and try it now. Or just remove that line.

What i believe is happening is that pic is of type picture. But what every ws.pictures is returning as a type doesn't equal picture

Comment: True 'dat. I found that simply removing the typedef and changing  `Dim pic As Picture` to `Dim pic` or `Dim pic As Variant` works out.

Comment: Tried but no change

Comment: Have you tried removing `Dim pic as Picture` completely

Comment: Removing completely worked. But again all form controls are also being deleted, i want to delete only pictures.

Comment: i have no experience in vba in excel.
but try `For Each pic In ws.Shapes`
maybe there is a way to check if a shape is a picture. as i think this will delete any shape you ask it to and shape probably includes picture, diagram and charts etc.

Answer (score 0):

The below code deletes only pictures in the sheet.
By checking Shape.Type = 11 for pictures.

```
Sub clearPics()
Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In Worksheets("sort").Shapes

        If shp.Type = 11 Then
                shp.Delete
        End If

    Next shp
End Sub
```